# Not able to update Attribute value in XmlNode

Tags: c#, xml

The code below works in C#, no error, no exception. The problem is that the `numconfig.xml` file won't change after running the code.

C# code:

```
XmlNodeList xm = new XmlManager(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Xml/numconfig.xml")).ReadAllChild(@"//number");
xm[0].SelectSingleNode("abc[@name='upper']").Attributes["value"].Value = "201";
```

Xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<number>
    <aaa>
        <abc value="200" text="xxxx" name="upper"/>
</aaa>
</number>
```

Comment: is the file is already open in explorer?

Comment: you just need to [save](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.XmlDocument.Save(v=vs.110).aspx) it!

Answer (score 0):

How are you trying to commit the changes back to the file? Your code does not show an example eg

```
using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(location))
{
    foreach (XmlNode xmlNode in xm)
    {
        streamWriter.WriteLine(xmlNode.OuterXml);
    }
}
```